# Read and save list of Object using list of interface

Tags: java, android, interface

> I have seen someone's code and unable to understand how it works.

As the code save List of object in list of Interfaces and can read it back.

Please explain how it works. And can we save Object in interface (where Object implements it). AFAIK interface doesn't have members. How this code save and retrieve please explain.

**ContactBO implementing BusinessObject**

```
public class ContactBO implements BusinessObject {

    private String id, fullName, department, ;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public String getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }

    public void setDepartment(String department) {
        this.department = department;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSection() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

}
```

**Where BussinessObject**

```
public interface BusinessObject {
    boolean isSection();
}
```

Saving list of Contact code

```
List<ContactBO> contactList = new Gson().fromJson(jsonArray.toString(),
                new TypeToken<List<ContactBO>>() {}.getType());
        List<BusinessObject> list = new ArrayList<BusinessObject>();
        list.addAll(contactList);
```

read List of ContactBO using List of Interface

```
List<ContactBO> contactListItems = (List<ContactBO>) (List<?>) result.list;//where list is public List<BusinessObject> list;
```

Comment: If you have `List<T> list` where `T` is an interface, the objects of the list can be objects of _any_ classes that implement the interface.  The objects themselves don't change when you put the in the list.  They still have the same class they have when they're created.  Please try reading a tutorial such as [this one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I can understand from the source.

```
List<ContactBO> contactList = new Gson().fromJson(jsonArray.toString(),
                new TypeToken<List<ContactBO>>() {}.getType());
```

This does not mean

> As the code save List of object in list of Interfaces and can read it
>   back

The above line converts response using GSON to a `List` object of **type** `ContactBO`. 
By implementing `BusinessObject` interface,  `ContactBO` is still a class and not an interface.

Now the next line

```
List<BusinessObject> list = new ArrayList<BusinessObject>();
```

This again creates a List of **type** `BusinessObject`

Now the following line. `list.addAll(contactList);` Adds object of type `ContactList` to super object which is of type `BusinessObject`

Comment: ContactBO is still a class and not an interface. Nice thumbs up and It means implementing interface (is a form of inheritance right)

Answer (score 0):

"Polymorphism is the ability of an object to take on many forms. The most common use of polymorphism in OOP occurs when a parent class reference is used to refer to a child class object."

```
   List<BusinessObject> list = new ArrayList<BusinessObject>();
```

This line basically show Polymorphsim concept, Parent class reference can hold the Child class object.

Answer (score 0):

When you cast an object of a class into an interface, which that class implements you can only access implemented method(s) that the interface has.

Comment: But I am still getting attributes from it.

Comment: @Nepster It's important to understand the difference between "the type as Java sees it", and "the type that's actually in the object".  If `Int` is an interface, and you have a variable `Int x;`, then Java knows that `x` has all the methods of `Int`, but it doesn't know anything else about `x`, so it can't let you access any other members with `x.member`.  But `x` was created with some concrete class, and it will always be in that class.  The other members will still be there, as long as Java knows that the object has that class...

Comment: @Nepster So if you say `Int x = something; Concrete y = (Concrete)x;` now Java knows that the object is `Concrete` (if it isn't, an exception will be thrown), so now you can access the members that were always in the object.